Solve a quasi-linear 1st order PDE by the method of characteristics
I'm trying to solve the following PDE
$$ yu_x + xu_y = u-1 $$
with the boundary condition $ u(x,2x) = (x+1)^2 $.
So I start with writing down Lagrange-Charpit equations
$$ dt = \frac{dx}{y} = \frac{dy}{x} = \frac{du}{u-1} $$
Integrating the first equality gives:
$$ y^2 = x^2 + C_1 $$
Applying the boundary condition at an arbitrary point, say $\epsilon$:
$$ 4\epsilon^2 = \epsilon^2 + C_1 \quad \rightarrow \quad y^2 = x^2 + 3\epsilon^2 $$
Now integrating the last equality
$$ u - 1 = C_2 \cdot e^{y/x} \quad \rightarrow \quad u  = C_2 \cdot e^{y/x} + 1$$
Applying the boundary condition at the same arbitrary point again:
$$ ( \epsilon + 1 )^2 = C_2 e^{2\epsilon / \epsilon} + 1 $$
Plugging in the expression we got for $\epsilon$ from before ($\epsilon = \sqrt{(y^2-x^2)/3}$):
$$ ( \sqrt{ \frac{y^2-x^2}{3} } + 1 )^2 = C_2 e^2 + 1 \quad \rightarrow \quad C_2(x,y) = \frac{ ( \sqrt{ \frac{y^2-x^2}{3} } + 1 )^2  - 1}{e^2} $$
But clearly I did this wrong because when I plug in this solution into the PDE it does not work! but I can't see it another way around this! Any tips?

Please explain the integration process in more detail. I see $x^2-y^2=c$ etc.

@LutzLehmann You're totally right I did the integration wrong, just updated the answer!

@ilra. Your error lies in $u-1 = C_2e^{y/x}$ (see my answer below).

The Lagrange-Charpit equations are
$$x'=y,\; y'=x,\; u'=u-1$$
With the solution
$$x(t)=c_1 e^{t}+ c_2 e^{-t},\; y(t)=c_1 e^{t}- c_2 e^{-t},\; u(t)=1+c_3 e^{t}$$
We find an invariant
$$-x^2(t)+y^2(t)=-4c_1 c_2$$
$$x(t)+y(t)=2c_2 e^{t}$$
Eliminating the integration constants $c_1,c_2,c_3$ and $t$ the general solution is given
$$u(x,y)=1+(x+y)\cdot f(-x^2+y^2)$$
The boundary condition $u(x,2x)=(x+1)^2$ leads to
$$1+3 x f\! \left(3 x^{2}\right)=\left(x+1\right)^{2}$$
or
$$f(3x^2)=\frac{x}{3} + \frac{2}{3}$$
$$f(x)=\pm\frac{\sqrt{3x}}{9}+\frac{2}{3}$$
Finally we get
$$u(x,y)=\begin{cases}
+\frac{\left(x+y\right) \sqrt{3(-x^{2}+y^{2})}}{9}+\frac{2}{3}(x+y)+1, & x\ge 0 \\
-\frac{\left(x+y\right) \sqrt{3(-x^{2}+y^{2})}}{9}+\frac{2}{3}(x+y)+1, & x< 0
\end{cases}$$
which also satisfies the BC $u(x,2x)=(x+1)^2$.

What a smart way to approach the problem! But I'm (generally) having difficulties trying to find an invariant as it is not very straightforward! Any tips on how to think here? Appreciate the help:))

The last Lagrange-Charpit equation, namely $\dot{u} = u-1$, can be integrated straighforwardly, hence $u(t) = Ae^t - 1$, with $A$ a constant (with respect to $t$).
The two other equations can be handled as you did, in order to express one variable in function of the other one; however, it is actually easier to differentiate again the Lagrange-Charpit, as done below :
$$
\begin{cases}
   \dot{x} = y \\
   \dot{y} = x
\end{cases}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\begin{cases}
   \ddot{x} = x \\
   \ddot{y} = y
\end{cases}
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
\begin{cases}
   x = x_0\cosh t + y_0\sinh t \\
   y = y_0\cosh t + x_0\sinh t
\end{cases}
$$
where $x_0 = x(t=0)$ and $y_0 = y(t=0)$ are constants of integration too.
Now, one needs to reparametrize the quantities $A$ and $t$ with the variables $x$ and $y$. Since $e^t = \cosh t + \sinh t = \frac{x+y}{x_0+y_0}$, one has $u = Ae^t + 1 = B(x+y) + 1$, with $B = \frac{A}{x_0+y_0}$. Your error originates precisely in the fact that you took $t = y/x$ mistakenly.
Moreover, the point $(x,y)$ lies on a hyperbola, in such a way that $x^2-y^2 = const$ doesn't depend on $t$, hence $B = f(x^2-y^2)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary function. One has thus $u(x,y) = (x+y)f(x^2-y^2) + 1$.
Finally, the given boundary condition yields $u(x,2x) = 3xf(-3x^2) + 1 = (x+1)^2$, hence $f(t) = -\frac{1}{3}\left(2\pm\sqrt{-\frac{t}{3}}\right)$ and $u(x,y) = 1 + \frac{x+y}{3}\left(2+\sqrt{-\frac{x^2-y^2}{3}}\right)$ in the end $-$ note that the "minus" solution has to be discarded, because it would imply $u(x,2x) = (x-1)^2$ instead.

Much easier to approach this way! Thank you so much sir!:)
